# Can /usr/bin/sftp resume file transfers?

Tags: ssh, sftp

I have a machine with only sftp access. No ssh, no shell, no rsync. When I get a file using /usr/bin/sftp, can I make it resume an aborted transfer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use lftp to auto sync all my photos from my NAS to my cheap webserver. If ever a photo changes it will automatically update it.

```
#!/bin/ash
SOURCE=/volume2/PHOTO/2011
BACKUPDIR=/foto.whatever.com/albums/2011

lftp -u username,password ftp.whatever.com << EOF
mirror -R -n -I *.jpg -I *.JPG -X @eaDir/ -X Collage/ -X ‘whatever/’ -X .piccache/ -X .recent/ -X Originals/ -X *.Db $SOURCE $BACKUPDIR
quit
```

Comment: Yup, a few minutes after I posted the question, I also found out about lftp, and I love it!

Answer (score 8):

You can use the option `-a` in the `get` command in `sftp` to resume a previously aborted download.

Example:

```
echo -e "lcd ~/localFolder\nget -ar *" | sftp username@host.com:/some/path
```

Alternatively written as

```
sftp username@host.com:/some/path <<EOF
lcd ~/localFolder
get -ar *
EOF
```

However this does not automatically reconnect to the server should the connection be interrupted. `lftp` is the better alternative for this problem.

Comment: Can't you just do `sftp -ar user@host:/some/path ~/localFolder` ?

Answer (score 5):

Current-day `sftp` supports the `reget` command to resume a download that was interrupted halfway.

Comment: There's also a `reput` command to resume an interrupted upload

Answer (score 1):

I just found the `lftp` program, and it supports `get -c` for resuming a download. If `sftp` can't do that, I think I'll stick with lftp.

Answer (score 1):

One liner with password-less ssh access looks as follows:

```
echo get -ar /file/path/file.data | sftp login@server
```